# what is the difference in using {} and using []

Tags: python, python-3.x, containers

I'm just wondering what is the difference between using {} and [].

e.g. a code snippet says:

```
parameters = {}
cost = []
```

I do not exactly understand the difference in using {} and []?

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets[] are used to create a list.

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Curly braces are for creating dictionary.

```
dc = {"key": "value"}
```

Both are compound data types.
These [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) are for further research.

Answer (score 1):

In python, these specify different types of data-structure.

`{}` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

`[]` is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

e.g.

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
my_dict = {"a": "apple", "b": "banana", "c": "clementine"}

print(my_list[0])
>>> "a"

print(my_dict["a"])
>>> "apple"
```

Answer (score 1):

{} are used to define a dictionary 
[] are used to access a value through a key in the dictionary created

Consider the following scenario 
inventory = {"gold" : 500, "silver" : 250}

The above one creates a new dictionary called inventory.

inventory["silver"] = 300 
The above line means that you are updating value for key "silver" in inventory dictionary.

For more information, check out the following link
https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/52d7004d9c4e9d60bb001fff

Answer (score 0):

In-built function `type` is very helpful in such cases:

```
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>> type({})
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(['a','b'])
<class 'list'>
>>> type({'a':1,'b':2})
<class 'dict'>
>>> type({1,2})
<class 'set'>
```